# <p> elements not included in height of containing <div>

Tags: html, css

I feel really silly having to ask this, but I haven't been able to find much info and I am having a strange issue. Basically, I have the following html:

```
<div class='one'>
    <div class='two'>
        <img src="someImage" class="img-responsive teamPhoto"/>
        <p>Some text</p>
        <p>Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

Simple enough. The issue that I am having is that when I look at the height of div one and two, the height is only equal to the nested image in div two.

It does not include the 'P' elements at all, and when I inspect in the browser I can see that both div's only extend as far as the bottom of the image.

What am I missing here that my paragraph elements are being excluded from the div height?

Comment: I like to see your css class. I believe there is an error on defining div floating property.

Comment: I think it has to do with element positioning? In diiv one, I have the position set to relative. Div two is set to absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see your css but I am pretty sure that there's something wrong with styles of 'one' and 'two' div. If you inspect the two div element in Chrome dev tool, try to disable all styles for the two div element and it should work.

Comment: It most definitely has to do with the styles...I can see that (using my above example) that div two has a style of 'position: absolute', while div one has a style of 'position: relative'. If I remove absolute the div encompasses all of the contained elements, but unfortunately I have to have it as absolute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='one'>
    <div class="two" style="position: absolute;background-color: #ccc;">
        <div>
            <img src="https://fyf.tac-cdn.net/images/products/large/TEV12-4.jpg" class="img-responsive teamPhoto">
            <p>Some text</p>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd put the image and p tag inside another div to solve your issue. The div one still has height = 0 though